# Hibernate Insert and Update failures with SQL Server 2014

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, sql-server-2014

We have recently upgraded our database to SQL Server 2014. We have a Hibernate Java application which transfers the data from excel to db. We are experiencing the intermittent insert and update failures. Any specific reason for same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you logging your Hibernate/SQL queries? What relevant code is causing this? We need more information to help you.

Comment: Hi Shawn, This was a working code with 2005 version. I am not logging any errors and SQL statements.